# How to approach an if conditional for bulma CSS dropdown HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an if conditional based on what city a user selects off the dropdown menu. It has presented itself a challenge because it's bulmas CSS dropdown which does not use `<selector>` and `<option>` but all `<div>`s.

```
// The Dropdown for Cities
const root = document.querySelector(".cities");
root.innerHTML = `
<div class='dropdown'>
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
    <span>Choose a City</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button> 
  </div>  
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <div class='dropdown-content'>
        <a href='#' id="myCity" value="oak" class='dropdown-item'>
          Oakland, CA
        </a>
        <a href='#' id="myCity" value="san" class='dropdown-item'>
          San Francisco, CA
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

I tried `value` as you can see, but that will not work.

```
const myCity = document.getElementById("myCity");

myCity.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
  if (
    <HTMLInputElement>(
      document.getElementById("dropdown-menu").value.includes("san")
    )
  ) {
    console.log("this will show us San Francisco");
  } else if (
    <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("dropdown-menu").value === "oak"
  ) {
    console.log("this will show us Oakland");
  } else {
    return null;
  }
});
```

Comment: You should not have different elements with the same ID, ID/s are supposed to be unique, you need to change these to classes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the dropdown `<a>` ids to class instead to prevent duplicate ids. Also use a `data-` attribute since `<a>` does not have value.

Then check the target of the event

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('#dropdown-menu')

document.querySelector('.dropdown-trigger button').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
   dropdown.classList.toggle('active');
});

dropdown.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
   e.preventDefault()
   if(e.target.matches('.dropdown-item.city')){
      const cityName = e.target.dataset.value;
      console.log('City =', cityName);
      dropdown.classList.toggle('active');
   }
})
```

```css
#dropdown-menu { display:none}
#dropdown-menu.active{display:block}
```

```html
<div class='dropdown'>
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
    <span>Choose a City</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button> 
  </div>  
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <div class='dropdown-content'>
        <a href='#' data-value="oak" class='city dropdown-item'>
          Oakland, CA
        </a>
        <a href='#' data-value="san" class='city dropdown-item'>
          San Francisco, CA
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get `Property 'matches' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'` when I attempt to use `if (e.target.matches(".dropdown-item.`